# Why is it "grand theft auto"?

Tags: word-order

I'm not a native speaker so it might just be me finding this strange, but why is the *auto* in *grand theft auto* at the end?

Shouldn't it be *grand auto theft* or something like this?

I thought the expression described the crime of stealing cars?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The term should be "Grand Theft, Auto". It is one of those officialese terms like IBS standing for "Inflatable Boat, Small". My guess is that it's based on the law ([in California, at least](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_theft)) making an exception for automobiles to the minimum value of property stolen in order to be considered grand, as opposed to petty, theft.

Comment: It also comes from the days when everything was on paper and you had to look up things in alphabetical order. It was a common practice to file things using a _category, subcategory_ system so all items of the same _category_ would be next to each other in the index or filing cabinet or book or catalog.  So why isn't it Theft, Grand, Auto? Because that would be a sub-subcategory, and that was too unwieldy for most uses, although it does show up here and there.

Comment: Seems to originate from the LA police department based on ngram:  Here's an example (no comma): https://books.google.com/books?id=JwjNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22grand+theft+auto%22&dq=%22grand+theft+auto%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPr8eHsoDOAhXCOT4KHWgxBtAQ6AEIHjAA

Answer (score -4):

any theft which is approx over a thousand in value,"grand" makes it a felony crime,also any automobile

Comment: [No, it's not](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/theft-shoplifting-crimes-32639-2.html).

Comment: The question is not in regards to the value of the theft, but the grammatical correctness of the term.  For the record, the dollar value of 'grand' varies by [state law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_theft), and may be as low as $200.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE]. Your post would be improved if it included a references to support your claims.
Please see the [help] to learn more about how to write a strong answer.